# React - webpack exports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

**Edit - Answer**: encapsulating the imports work as required:

```
# index.js
var myLibrary {
    ProfileApp: require('./components/ProfileApp.react'),
    ProfileStore: require('./stores/ProfileStore'),
}
module.exports = myLibrary;
```

I can now do

```
var lib = require('myLibrary');
var ProfileApp = lib.ProfileApp;
```

**End of edit**

I have developped a react/flux libray which I need to package using webpack. I do this for the first time and my exports seem wrong... (the library itself works well). 
My (simplified) index.js file is

```
# index.js
module.exports = require('./components/ProfileApp.react'); 
module.exports = require('./stores/ProfileStore');
...
```

The code is correctly compiled and installed in node_modules, but does not work when imported.

```
# whatever.file.doing.imports
var myLibrary = require('myLibrary'); # works well
var ProfileApp = myLibrary.ProfileApp; # works only if I call it --> myLibrary.ProfileApp()
var ProfileStore = myLibrary.ProfileStore; # does not work and  myLibrary.ProfileStore() raises "is not a function error"
```

I think my exports in index.js should use another syntax. For instance, React Router (https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/modules/index.js) uses

```
export Router from './Router'; 
# which can be simply instantiated writing
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
```

This syntax raises an error when used in my library. Do you know if I have to use plugin to be able to use this syntax, or if I can write it differently?
Thank you very much!

Comment: what's your webpack config?

Comment: Hi knowbody! I copied exactly https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/webpack.config.js, just adding "path: path.resolve('./modules'), filename: "module.js"" in the output section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special export syntax that React Router uses is from ES6 and is "transpiled" by the Babel loader that you see in use in the webpack config on line 23.  Also note that that line only applies to files that have a ".js" extension.  Since you have files with ".react" extensions, you may need to change that line.

Unfortunately that does not explain your issue with having to call `ProfileApp` as a function.  Maybe if you posted the code for the ProfileApp and ProfileStore, that would help.